# python [lxml] - cleaning out html tags

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

```
from lxml.html.clean import clean_html, Cleaner
    def clean(text):
        try:        
            cleaner = Cleaner(scripts=True, embedded=True, meta=True, page_structure=True, links=True, style=True,
                      remove_tags = ['a', 'li', 'td'])
            print (len(cleaner.clean_html(text))- len(text))
            return cleaner.clean_html(text) 
        except:
            print 'Error in clean_html'
            print sys.exc_info()
            return text
```

I put together the above (ugly) code as my initial forays into python land. I'm trying to use lxml cleaner to clean out a couple of html pages, so in the end i am just left with the text and nothing else - but try as i might, the above doesnt appear to work as such, i'm still left with a substial amount of markup (and it doesnt appear to be broken html), and particularly links, which aren't getting removed, despite the args i use in `remove_tags` and `links=True`

any idea whats going on, perhaps im barking up the wrong tree with lxml ? i thought this was the way to go with html parsing in python?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950131/python-lxml-cleaning-out-html-tags/2950223#2950223 as input. Could you provide a sample of the html and the desired output?

Comment: ~unutbu this is most strange - i have a whole database where that code did not work - and yet, it seems to be working just fine now? (did you do something :) ?)

but whilst im at it, any idea how you could also take the link-text out, when removing the link (because atm it leaves the text of the links in).

Comment: @sadhu_: `remove_tags` removes only tags themselves; it leaves its children and text. Use `kill_tags` to remove the whole  tree.

Answer (score 15):

solution from [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332984/565525) concatenates the text with no separator:

```
   import lxml.html
   document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_string)
   # internally does: etree.XPath("string()")(document)
   print document.text_content()
```

but this one helped me - concatenation the way I needed:

```
   from lxml import etree
   print "\n".join(etree.XPath("//text()")(document))
```

Comment: This is much more useful.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this method existed around the time you made your question, but if you go through

```
document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_text)
raw_text = document.text_content()
```

That should return you all the text content in the html document, minus all the markup.

Comment: Check out Robert's answer below - link for lazy http://stackoverflow.com/a/23929354/9908

Answer (score 5):

I think you should check out [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Use the advice from [this article](http://www.ghastlyfop.com/blog/2008/12/strip-html-tags-from-string-python.html) and strip the HTML elements in the following way:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

''.join(BeautifulSoup(page).findAll(text=True))
```

Where `page` is your string of html.

Should you need further clarification, you can check out the Dive into Python case study on [HTML parsing](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html).

Comment: It seems BS is deprecated (and googling seems to suggest lxml is the way forward..)so ideally i wanted to learn some lxml [as the documentation is mildly bewildering..]

Comment: BS rocks! With 4.0 rc out (a few months ago) you can use the parser from `lxml` or `html5lib` and wrap them in the nice BS api.