# How to get rid of html tags and javascript functions from the scraped data?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a scrapy project and the data I require is getting scraped also.

But the problem is the scraped data contains a lot of unwanted things like Javascript functions and other html tags. How to get rid of them and get only the data?

My `testSpider.py` code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from testing.items import testingItem

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testspider'
    session_id = -1
    start_urls = ["https://www.wikipedia.org/"]
    rules = ( Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("", ),),
                callback="parse_items",  follow= True),
    )

    def __init__(self, session_id=-1, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session_id = session_id

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        item = testingItem()
        item["session_id"] = self.session_id
        item["depth"] = response.meta["depth"]
        # item["current_url"] = response.url
        # referring_url = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
        # item["referring_url"] = referring_url
        item["title"] = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        item["content"]=sel.xpath('content/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items



    My items.py:

    from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    class testingItem(Item):
        session_id =Field()
        depth = Field()
        current_url=Field()
        referring_url =Field()
        title=Field()
        content=Field()
```

Comment: Why don't you just adjust your xpath selectors to extract what you only need?

Comment: Actually as i need all the content i specified the xpath as ''content/text()'' .so it takes all the content.I tried to find how to specify a xpath avoiding what is not required ,but i couldnt find a solution.Is there a way to do that???I tried changing the restrict _paths in the rules as:    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("", ),restrict_xpaths=('//*/script'),),
              callback="parse_items",  follow= True),
     )  .So that it will restrict all scripts.But even this didnt work..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3973325/7432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't extract what you need exactly then you need to create some function or class to clean data for you, as separated part. Call it inside your parse function. For example

utils.py

```
class Cleaner(object):

    def clean_html_tags(data):
        ....
        return data

    def clean_empty_space(data):
        ...
        return data
```

Then in your parse function you can use something like:

```
from spider.utils import Cleaner

...

 def parse(self, response):
    item['something'] = Cleaner.clean_html_tags(selector.xpath("//div[@class='myclass']/div/text()").extract())
```