# How to get the content from a certain <table> using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some `<tr>`s, like this:

```
<tr align=center><td>10876151</td><td><a href=userstatus?user_id=yangfanhit>yangfanhit</a></td><td><a href=problem?id=3155>3155</a></td><td><font color=blue>Accepted</font></td><td>344K</td><td>219MS</td><td>C++</td><td>3940B</td><td>2012-10-02 16:42:45</td></tr>
<tr align=center><td>10876150</td><td><a href=userstatus?user_id=BandBandRock>BandBandRock</a></td><td><a href=problem?id=2503>2503</a></td><td><font color=blue>Accepted</font></td><td>16348K</td><td>2750MS</td><td>G++</td><td>840B</td><td>2012-10-02 16:42:25</td></tr>
```

I want to fetch the content without html tags, like:

```
yangfanhit
3155
Accepted
344K
219MS
C++
3940B
2012-10-02 16:42:45
```

Now I'm using the following code to deal with it:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://poj.org/status', timeout=10)
html = response.read()
response.close()

pattern = re.compile(r'<tr align.*</tr>')
match = pattern.findall(html)
pat = re.compile(r'<td>.*?</td>')
p = re.compile(r'<[/]?.*?>')
for item in match:
    for i in pat.findall(item):
        print p.sub(r'', i)
    print '================================================='
```

I'm new to regex and also new to python. So could you suggest some better methods to process it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with RegEx. Tony the Pony will eat you alive. Please use a proper parser instead. lxml comes built in to Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip html from strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the html. To write the content of the table in csv format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://poj.org/status'))

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for tr in soup.find('table', 'a')('tr'):
    writer.writerow([td.get_text() for td in tr('td')])
```

#### Output

```
Run ID,User,Problem,Result,Memory,Time,Language,Code Length,Submit Time
10876151,yangfanhit,3155,Accepted,344K,219MS,C++,3940B,2012-10-02 16:42:45
10876150,BandBandRock,2503,Accepted,16348K,2750MS,G++,840B,2012-10-02 16:42:25
```

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [PyQuery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/). Very easy to pickup if you're familiar with jQuery. Here's an example that returns table header and data as list of dictionaries.

```
import itertools
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

# parse html
html = pq(url="http://poj.org/status")

# extract header values from table
header = [header.text for header in html(".a").find(".in").find("td")]

# extract data values from table rows in nested list
detail = [[td.text for td in tr] for tr in html(".a").children().not_(".in")]

# merge header and detail to create list of dictionaries
result = [dict(itertools.izip(header, values)) for values in detail]
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to work with regex directly to parse html, [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950223/492620).

Or see [Dive into Python Chapter 8](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html) about HTML Processing.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing those things when you already got HTML/ XML parsers which does the job easily for you

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Considering what you want as mentioned in the above question, it can be done in 2-3 lines of code.

Example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> html = """
<tr align=center><td>10876151</td><td><a href=userstatus?user_id=yangfanhit>yangfanhit</a></td><td><a href=problem?id=3155>3155</a></td><td><font color=blue>Accepted</font></td><td>344K</td><td>219MS</td><td>C++</td><td>3940B</td><td>2012-10-02 16:42:45</td></tr>
<tr align=center><td>10876150</td><td><a href=userstatus?user_id=BandBandRock>BandBandRock</a></td><td><a href=problem?id=2503>2503</a></td><td><font color=blue>Accepted</font></td><td>16348K</td><td>2750MS</td><td>G++</td><td>840B</td><td>2012-10-02 16:42:25</td></tr>
"""

>>>soup = bs(html)
>>>soup.td
>>><td>10876151</td>
```