# Extract text with lxml.html

Tags: python, lxml

I have a HTML file:

```
<html>
    <p>somestr
        <sup>1</sup>
       anotherstr
    </p>
</html>
```

I would like to extract the text as:

somestr<sup>1</sup>anotherstr

but I can't figure out how to do it. I have written a `to_sup()` function  that converts numeric strings to superscript so the closest I get  is something like:

```
for i in doc.xpath('.//p/text()|.//sup/text()'):
    if i.tag == 'sup':
        print to_sup(i),
    else:
        print i,
```

but I `ElementStringResult` doesn't seem to have a method to get the tag name, so I am a bit lost. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Well, then omit text() from the query and extract the text directly from the nodes.

Comment: @ user1833746 -- tried `for x in doc.xpath("//p|//sup"):print(x.text)`, but this only outputs `somestr1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't call `text()` on the `sup` nodes in the XPath.

```
for x in doc.xpath("//p/text()|//sup"):
    try:
        print(to_sup(x.text))
    except AttributeError:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 9):

first solution (concatenates text with no separator - see also [python [lxml] - cleaning out html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950131/python-lxml-cleaning-out-html-tags)):

```
   import lxml.html
   document = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_string)
   # internally does: etree.XPath("string()")(document)
   print document.text_content()
```

this one helped me - concatenation the way I needed:

```
   from lxml import etree
   print "\n".join(etree.XPath("//text()")(document))
```